# iOS 16 NavigationStack bouncing back to root

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Im having an odd issue trying to implement NavigationStack{} in my application - I think it has something to do with the fact that my destination has multiple dynamic lists and they are updating?

I've come across some of the same questions but no real response. When I removed the navigation stack from the destination view the problem goes away.

[image]

Main View

```
    struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var accountData = AccountData()
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List {
                Section("Accounts") {
                    ForEach(account) { account in
                        NavigationLink(value: account) {
                            Text(account.mainInformation.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section("Contacts") { 
                    ForEach(account) { account in
                        let contact = account.contacts
                        ForEach(contact) { contact in
                            NavigationLink(value: contact) {
                                Text(contact.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Account.self) { account in
                AccountDetailView(account: binding(for: account))
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Contact.self) { contact in
                Text(contact.name)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Categories")
    }

 extension TestView {
    var account: [Account] {
        accountData.accounts
    }
    
    // Finding the index of a particular account in the data model array
    func binding(for account: Account) -> Binding<Account> {
        guard let index = accountData.index(of: account) else {
            fatalError("Account not found")
        }
        return $accountData.accounts[index]
    }
}
```

Destination View

```
struct AccountDetailView: View {
 
@Binding var account: Account
@State private var isPresenting = false

var body: some View {
        
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .blur(radius: 1)
                    .clipShape (RoundedShape (corners: [.bottomRight])).shadow(radius: 8)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom, -140)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(account.mainInformation.address)
                            .padding(.horizontal,  10)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, -20)
                    Text(account.mainInformation.city)
                        .padding(.horizontal,  10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(account.mainInformation.number)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
                Divider()
                // Lists for supporting contacts and tasks
                
                List {
                    Section("Contacts") {
                        ForEach(account.contacts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            let contact = account.contacts[index]
                            ContactListRow(contact: contact)
                        }
                    }
                    Section("Tasks") {
                        ForEach(account.tasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            let task = account.tasks[index]
                            Text(task.action)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        // Navigation title for account name - Compatability with NavStack?
        .navigationTitle(account.mainInformation.name)
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
        //.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        
        // SHEET CODE for sheet that presents on edit
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                HStack {
                    Button("Edit") {
                        isPresenting = true
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
            NavigationStack {
                ModifyAccountView(account: $account)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Save") {
                                isPresenting = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    
    
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose you have two `view1` and `view2`. There is variable **a** that is bind with-in view1 and also passing to view 2. Now if you change the variable **a** from view2 in any why the SwiftUI will automatically pop all the view from the NavigationStack to the current view which have declared that variable **a**. You are also passing some bind variable to `AccountDetailView`  you need to carefully exam either any value is chaining on Navigation push which is bind in the `TestView` . I have gone through these two swift file I did't see any change is happing but you need to go through you whole code and find any chaning value.

Comment: Thank you for the info - Quick question though, what if I want to change the data in View 2? (accountDetailView) should I not have a binding?

Comment: yes you can bind the data, but it does not attached with any navigationLink so that it does't cause any pop action.